# How to remove percentage calculation on top of bar in ng2-chart bar chart

Tags: angular5, chart.js, ng2-charts

I am trying to create bar chart using ng2-chart in angular 5. It is creating fine but i think i am missing some configuration due to which i am getting percentage calculation on top of maximum 2 bars. i want to remove these percentage

i am using ng2-charts(1.6.0), chart.js(2.7.2) in package.json.
I have tried configuration available on chartjs.org for bar chart but not able to remove the percentage calculation for those bars.
[image: Please see yellow highlighted which i want to remove]
In html

```
<canvas baseChart
    height='260px'
    [datasets]="barChartData"
    [labels]="barChartLabels"
    [options]="barChartOptions"
    [colors]="chartColors"
    [legend]= "false"
    [chartType]="barChartType">
</canvas>
```

In Component

```
public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: { xAxes: [{}], yAxes: [{ticks: {beginAtZero: true}}] },
    plugins: { datalabels: { anchor: 'end', align: 'end', } }
};

public barChartData = [ { data: [7,4,1,5,3,1,2,1]} ],
public barChartLabels = ['25/03','26/03','27/03','28/03','29/03','30/03','31/03','01/04','02/04',],
public chartColors = [ {backgroundColor: '#fa9cb0'} ]
```

i want simple bar without those random percentage on top of those bar.
Just for info, it is coming for only small value. For values like

```
[12,22,34,53,65,73,23,45]
```

It is fine.

Please let me know, how can i remove those percentage from top of bar. Is there any other configuration i need to use??

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using old versions of libraries? `ng2-charts` is now at 2.2.2 and `chart.js`is at 2.8.0

Comment: Due to project restrictions. Can't update any library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I futher looked in the issue and found out that in my project global plugin was created which was wrongly implemented for every type of chart without any configrable property.

```
Chart.plugins.register({ // plugin implementation });
```

Refering to this link [ChartJs Plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin: 'chartjs-plugin-labels' to solve the issue, here is the info to add the plugin to your Angular project:

https://emn178.github.io/chartjs-plugin-labels/

After you have the plugin installed in your project you have to add the library in the .ts file of the chart with this code snippet:

```js
import 'chartjs-plugin-labels';
```

and in the plugins variable section add this code also:

```js
 labels: {
  render: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to import ChartDataLabels and then unregister 'ChartDataLabels' plugin

```
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

Chart.plugins.unregister(ChartDataLabels);  // on ngAfterViewInit
```